# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'QgsComposerMap'

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, python-3

I am trying to import `QgsComposerMap` in my `QGIS3` plugin but I always get this error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'QgsComposerMap'`. 
My import looks like this: 
`from qgis.core import QgsRectangle, QgsComposerMap, QgsPointXY as QgsPoint`
 The API changes don't say anything about changes of this module. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer has been dropped from QGIS 3.0, replaced by a brand new layouts engine. See QgsLayout, QgsLayoutItem and related classes in the API docs.